# which is the best method to move php code out of js in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am developing an application in Yii.. One issue i am facing is, when i am writing ajax functions, the url's will be in php. so i am unable to move the codes to another javascript file.

```
$.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('provider/ajaxdetail');?>",
             data: {'type':tagtype},
             beforeSend: function() { },
             success: function(data) {

                        }                   

             });
```

so what is the best method to move php out of the javascript so that i can move the javascript code to another js file.  I Thought of putting the url's in a hidden box and then call it in the javascript function. but i hope there will be better methods to do this .

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could create a global variable to store the url, in your html `head` , so that any js file that needs the url can access it, like:

```
<html>
...
<head>
..
var MY_APP_URL = '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>'; //can be like www.somesite.com/
....
//load js files
...
```

and in the js file you could do:

```
$.ajax({
  url: MY_APP_URL + "controller_name/function_name",
   data: {'type':tagtype},
```

OR you could do:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('helpers', '
        someUrl = '.CJSON::encode(Yii::app()->createUrl('blabla')).';
        baseUrl = '.CJSON::encode(Yii::app()->baseUrl).';
');?>
```

and you can use variables `someUrl` and `baseUrl` in your Javascript files